# Non-invocable member 'System.Xml.XmlNode.Attributes' cannot be used like a method

Tags: c#, vb.net

I am new to C# and trying to convert a VB.NET app.  Using this code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.XPath;

namespace TestXML
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlDataDocument Doc = new XmlDataDocument();
            XmlNodeList nodeList;
            XmlElement Element;
            XmlNode node = null;
            Doc.Load(@"UNC path of a doc.xml file");
            Element = Doc.DocumentElement;
            nodeList = Element.SelectNodes("Application");
            foreach (XmlNode node in nodeList)
            {
                if (node.Attributes(@"Name").InnerText = @"Something")
                    break;
            }
            //gsCurrentMode is one of "Production","Test","Develope"
            nodeList = node.SelectNodes("Instance");
            foreach (XmlNode n in nodeList)
            {
                if (node.Attributes("Mode").Value = @"Production")
                    //if either of these two fails, Something shuts down
                    return node.Attributes("Server").InnerText;
                else
                {
                    return;
                }
            }       
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting the following errors:
1.  A local variable named 'node' cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to 'node', which is already used in a 'parent or current' scope to denote something else for these statements: (XmlNode node in nodeList)
2.  Non-invocable member 'System.Xml.XmlNode.Attributes' cannot be used like a method for the node.Attributes lines.

The orignal VB.NET code is as follows:

```
Public Function GetProductionServer() As String
        Dim Doc As New XmlDocument
        Dim nodeList As XmlNodeList
        Dim Element As XmlElement
        Dim node As XmlNode = Nothing
        Doc.Load("UNC Path to an Doc.xml")
        Element = Doc.DocumentElement
        nodeList = Element.SelectNodes("Application")
        For Each node In nodeList
            If node.Attributes("Name").InnerText = "Something" Then
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        '--- gsCurrentMode is one of "Production","Test","Develope"
        nodeList = node.SelectNodes("Instance")
        For Each node In nodeList
            If node.Attributes("Mode").Value = "Production" Then
                '-- if either of these two fails, Something shuts down
                Return node.Item("Server").InnerText
            End If
        Next
        Return ""
    End Function
```

Can someone please give me some guidance, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

1. Your foreach loop needs to use a different name than `node` because it is used outside of the loop.
2. Your `if` statement should have `==` to show that you are comparing two values and not assigning one to the other.
3. Whenever you are referring to an array of items, in C# you use `[]` instead of `()`.  This will solve your **cannot be used like a method** problems.

Try something like this:

```
foreach (XmlNode n in nodeList)
{
    if (n.Attributes["Name"].InnerText == "Aurora NET")
    //NOTE: You've found the node, but you aren't actually doing anything here.
    break;
}
```

Another thing: You have created a console application for this project, but your original code was actually a function that returned a string.  The `Main()` method has a `void` return type which is the equivalent of a `Sub` in VB.  You should probably make this into a method (VB function) in C# that returns a string.

Answer (score 0):

*1. A local variable named 'node' cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to 'node', which is already used in a 'parent or current' scope to denote something else for these statements: (XmlNode node in nodeList)*

You're defining the variable `node` twice

Here

`XmlNode node = null;`

and Here:

```
foreach (XmlNode node in nodeList)
```

name `node` something else in your `foreach`.

---

*2. Non-invocable member 'System.Xml.XmlNode.Attributes' cannot be used like a method for the node.Attributes lines.*

You're using parenthesis where you should be using square brackets.
Change
`if (node.Attributes(@"Name").InnerText = @"Something")`

to

`if (node.Attributes[@"Name"].InnerText = @"Something")`

(this appears multiple times in your code)

Comment: Thanks All.  Had a week training in C# and my brain is a bit mushy this week.  I added a few comments in my code to remind myself of some of the basic differences from VB.  Your help was much appreciated.

Comment: You can upvote any answers which have helped you, and if one of them answers your question, you can mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Question 1**

You cannot reuse variable names within a function, you'll need to define it as something else, so this:

```
foreach (XmlNode node in nodeList)
{
    if (node.Attributes(@"Name").InnerText = @"Something")
        break;
}
```

Should probably be:

```
foreach (XmlNode nn in nodeList)
{
    if (n.Attributes(@"Name").InnerText = @"Something")
        break;
}
```

**Question 2**

This:

```
return node.Attributes("Server").InnerText;
```

should be:

```
return node.Attributes["Server"].InnerText;
```

as an example.

Pretty much anywhere you use `node.Attributes(*)` it should be `node.Attributes[*]`. In VB, the indexer is called using the same syntax as a method invocation. In C# we use brackets ('[', ']') in indexers.

---

Adjusted code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    XmlDataDocument Doc = new XmlDataDocument();
    XmlNodeList nodeList;
    XmlElement Element;
    XmlNode node = null;
    Doc.Load(@"UNC path of a doc.xml file");
    Element = Doc.DocumentElement;
    nodeList = Element.SelectNodes("Application");
    foreach (XmlNode n in nodeList)
    {
        if (n.Attributes[@"Name"].InnerText = @"Something")
            break;
    }
    //gsCurrentMode is one of "Production","Test","Develope"
    nodeList = node.SelectNodes("Instance");
    foreach (XmlNode n in nodeList)
    {
        if (node.Attributes["Mode"].Value = @"Production")
            //if either of these two fails, Something shuts down
            return node.Attributes["Server"].InnerText;
        else
        {
            return;
        }
    }       
}
```

Also note that:

```
if (node.Attributes[@"Name"].InnerText = @"Something")
```

is needlessly specifying the `@` on the strings because it doesn't matter if they're escaped or not.